# How to change jwt secret in Tymon's JWT Auth package at runtime to encode token for different hosts (subdomains)

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'm building multi-tenant app and I want to set different jwt secret for each of the tenant. I created middleware for this purpose where I get jwt_secret for active tenant and set it using the Config facade like this:

```
Config::set('jwt.secret', Tenant::getActiveTenant()->jwt_secret);
```

After this I dump the config setting and it shows the correct new value, but the package itself doesn't use it, but if I change the database connection setting to 'tenant' value during runtime, the package uses it correctly...

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

...

JWTAuth::getJWTProvider()->setSecret('foobarbaz');
```

See details here https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/503

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by directly setting the secret over the setSecret() method:

```
JWTAuth::manager()->getJWTProvider()->setSecret(Tenant::getActiveTenant()->jwt_secret);
```

It is not the prettiest soulution but for now it solves the problem...